# Automatically insert attribute above C# property in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'd like to create some sort of Visual Studio add on where I could hover over a line like:

```
public int counter {get; set;}
```

and upon selecting my menu item (or light bulb), it would insert a line similar to the following above it:

```
[DataMember Order=1]
public int counter {get; set;}
```

I found this example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903708.aspx

but I'm not sure it's taking me in the right direction. I was thinking that adding a menu item might make sense (so I could bind it to a keyboard shortcut), but the tricky part would be intelligently setting the "Order" parameter based on an observation of other instances of that attribute nearby.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a good way. We don't do general suggestions here, that's way to broad. If you don't see problems, try to implement it and ask any question that may arise from that in a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your digging in the right direction. You might also be interested in the [LightBulb extensibilty sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/LightBulb) on GitHub.

Additionally, I'd recommend looking into the [Roslyn code analysis APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx). The VS 2015 Roslyn based compilers might make it a bit easier to ID where you want those lightbulbs.